# instance variable access (via self) results in a null pointer dereference

Tags: iphone, dereference

Running an analysis on my app results in the logical error in the subject. I don't really know what that means. Below is a screen of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The path it's showing you is `super` returning `nil`. If this happens, you continue to execute the method; the implicit self deference is because `isShowingLandscapeView` is an instance variable. You need to put all your initialisation inside the `if (self)` block to avoid this.

Comment: +1 because I didn't know that accessing an ivar would dereference the object!